# Realtime Nationwide (or as many states possible) Auto Crash/Incident data

Tags: data-request, cars, police

I'm looking to create a database that will pull Realtime Nationwide (or as many states possible) Auto Crash/Incident information with the inclusion of the people that were involved in the incident(s) first, last name, age and the incident type [auto_accident_personal_injury].

An example that has some of the information I need is here https://data.vbgov.com/Public-Safety/Police-Incident-Reports/iqkq-gr5p/data- but it does not include the first, last name, age which is public information. Wondering if there is a way to also grab this in Open Data Network?

I've looked for weeks now and cannot figure this out. Any help would be awesome! I'm willing to hire someone to help me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how realtime this is, but [LexisNexis® Community Crime Map](http://LexisNexis%C2%AE%20Community%20Crime%20Map) (which appears not to be paywalled) lists traffic incidents.